# Insert control codes using Aulux Barcode Maker software

Tags: barcode

I have an Enterprise version of Aulux Barcode Label Maker and I want to insert some control codes into a barcode. It has a function to do that but it doesn't have all the control codes I need. I need the GS group separator, EOT and RS record separator. It has the RS but not the other 2. Does anyone know how to add to their control codes?

Their website has no phone number and they are very slow to respond to emails.